# Export Contacts without Person Accounts

Tags: migration, data-migration

may I ask you one question, is there any easy way to export Contacts without Person Accounts.

Currently I am trying to work with Helperfelds in the SOQL Query but wasn not successful, sadly. Still getting Person Accounts even though only exporting contacts..

Do you have any idea, workaround or have you had similar issues?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: PersonAccount mirrors some fields to Contact. That is, your question is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please edit and clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: THank you! I try to export Contacts without Record Type. We currently have 3 Record Types on Contacts, some of the Contacts (older ones) does not have a record type. Therefore I tried to export contacts without a record type but there also some Person accounts in my exports. I know from a technical perspective Person accounts have an accountId and a contactId.

I tried to create a helper field (formula / boolean) which basically says If ContactName != Account.Name, true else false. Did not work because of data quality.

Comment: The Contact that is "linked" to PersonAccount is still a Contact. If you want to exclude such Contact records, you have to filter them out based on Contact.Id = Account.PersonContactId. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_personaccounts.htm for more info.